# Get data from two collections with match stage on both in golang and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

My mongodb collections are

```
employee
{
  _id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"qwert",
  "emp_id":111,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
  "qualification":"PHD",
   "employee_status":"working"
}
{
_id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"asdfg",
  "emp_id":121,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
 "qualification":"MBA"
 "employee_status":"working"
}
department{
_id:ObjectId(),
"dept_id":11,
"dept_name":"XYZ",
"description":"decs",
"department_status":"active"
}
```

My Go Code is

```
 type DepartmentInfo struct {
    DepartmentID    int                `json:"dept_id" bson:"dept_id"`
    DepartmentName  string             `json:"dept_name" bson:"dept_name"` 
    Description     string             `json:"description" bson:"description"` 
    EmployeeCount   int                `json:"employee_count" bson:"employee_count"`
}

collection := session.DB("db").C("employee")
pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{
        {"$match": bson.M{ "qualification": "PHD", }},
        {"$group": bson.M{"_id": "$emp_dept",}},
        {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "from":         "department",
        "localField":   "_id",
        "foreignField": "dept_name",
        "as":           "department_info",
    }},
     {"$unwind": "$department_info"},
     {"$match": bson.M{"$or": []interface{}{
        bson.M{"department_info.status": bson.M{"$exists": false}},
        bson.M{"department_info.status": 1}, // department 1 means active
    }}},   
    })
var departmentInfo [] Department
err = pipeline.All(&departmentInfo)
```

It returns list with all struct values empty but when I used  `var documentInfo []interface{}` and print this,it display all the values. So how to bind the values to struct slice?

`and`

I want to get `EmployeeCount` last field in struct. It will be calculated as total no of employees in that particular department(group by) without any match stage like qualification.

I want output like

```
{
   dept_id:11,
   dept_name:'XYZ'
   description:'desc'
   employee_count:10
}
{
   dept_id:12,
   dept_name:'ABC'
   description:'desc'
   employee_count:20
}
................
```

1. First Filter data from employee collection having  PHD degree.
2. Get department name for that employee and get Department info from department collection.
3. Then check department should be Active
4. calculate employee count for that particular department with condition like `emp_dept=XYZ` and `employee_status=working`.

how to do this?